# Host Verifier issue with com.paytm.pgsdk.i

Tags: android, security, hostname, paytm

I am facing a Hostname Verifier  issue when i upload my app in  android playstore.and it says i am using a vulnerable class com.paytm.pgsdk.i. So can anyone tell me what to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently faced the similar issue while uploading my apk to play store.

All you need to do is just contact the paytm support and tell them this issue.

They will provide you with the new paytm sdk. Just replace the old sdk with this new one and you are done.